# Minimal memory ordering to ensure functionality and prevent compiler re-ordering in a lock-free non-circular MPSC queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, lock-free, stdatomic

The following API is used by multiple threads updating buckets in a buffer, while a single consumer processes them. Until MAX_CAPACITY is reached.

```
    struct Bucket {
        std::atomic<int> lock{0};
        Data data;
    };

    std::atomic<int64_t> readIndex{0};
    std::atomic<int64_t> writeIndex{0}; //expected to always be >= readIndex
    std::array<Bucket, MAX_CAPACITY> buffer;

    //Called from multiple updater threads
    bool updateData(/* arguments */) {
        while (true) {
            int64_t myWriteIndex = writeIndex.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
            if (myWriteIndex == MAX_CAPACITY) {
                return false; //Buffer full
            }
            Bucket& bucket = buffer[myWriteIndex];
            int expected = 0;
            if (bucket.lock.compare_exchange_strong(expected, 1, std::memory_order_relaxed)) { //Ensures processData is able to read the bucket only after any of its writers (specially the one updating bucket.data) that succeeded on the CAS releases bucket.lock
                //Several threads can end up here
                if (writeIndex.compare_exchange_strong(myWriteIndex, myWriteIndex + 1, std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
                    //Only 1 thread will be able to increment 'writeIndex'
                    //update bucket.data 
                    bucket.lock.store(0, std::memory_order_release); //Sync1
                    break;
                }
                bucket.lock.store(0, std::memory_order_release);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    //Called from just 1 consumer thread
    processData() {
        while (true) {
            int64_t myReadIndex = readIndex.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
            if (myReadIndex == writeIndex.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
                return false; //No more buckets to process
            }
            ...
            Bucket& bucket = buffer[myReadIndex];
            if (bucket.lock.load(std::memory_order_acquire) != 0) { //Sync1; writers lock the buffer while trying to update it
                continue;
            }
            //process bucket.data, then destroy it
            readIndex.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
            return true;
       }
    }
```

In updateData(): do I really need acquire/release ordering for writeIndex?
I do not believe so because:

(1) bucket.lock enables acquire/release ordering between updateData() and processData(), which is enough to ensure updates to Bucket::data done by the former are visible to the latter.

(2) bucket.lock.compare_exchange_strong(), even with std::memory_order_relaxed, ensures all updater threads see the latest value of bucket.lock.

(3) In updateData(): I do not expect compiler re-ordering of the conditionals for bucket.lock.compare_exchange_strong() and writeIndex.compare_exchange_strong() as that would seem to break the "as-if" rule.

Please share your thoughts.

Follow up: updateData() can be re-written more concisely and assertively with the help of a scope lock class

```
    struct ScopeLock {
        ScopeLock(std::atomic<int>& lock_) : lock(lock_) {}
        bool tryLock() {
            int expected = 1;
            locked = lock.compare_exchange_strong(expected, 1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        } 
        ~ScopeLock() {
            if (locked) {
                lock.store(0, std::memory_order_release); //Sync1
            }
        }
        bool locked;
        std::atomic<int>& lock;
    }

    bool updateData(/* arguments */) {
        while (true) {
            int64_t myWriteIndex = writeIndex.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); 
            if (myWriteIndex == MAX_CAPACITY) {
                return false; //Buffer full
            }
            Bucket& bucket = buffer[myWriteIndex];
            ScopeLock sl(bucket.lock);
            if (sl.tryLock() && 
                writeIndex.compare_exchange_strong(myWriteIndex, myWriteIndex + 1, std::memory_order_relaxed)) { //Short-circuit guarantees compile-time reordering will not happen between the && operands
                    //update bucket.data 
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

So regarding the scenario mentioned in one of my comments:

- the reader finds that readIndex = writeIndex = n, and starts looping.
- a writer locks Bucket::lock for bucket n (mo release) and succeeds incrementing writeIndex.
- while the writer is modifying Bucket::data (i.e. ScopeLock destructor has not run yet), the reader sees that writeIndex is now = n+1, so it can load Bucket::lock (mo acquire).

Given the acquire/release ordering on Bucket::lock and the fact that reader already saw writeIndex incremented to n+1: would the C++ ISO or any cache coherent architecture allow for the reader to see/load a value of 0 for the memory location corresponding to (buffer[myReadIndex = n]).lock ?

PS RMW handling of cache lines discussed here: [Synchronization of std::atomic::compare_exchange_weak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67173500/synchronization-of-stdatomiccompare-exchange-weak)

PPS I'm writing this code for x86-64, but I'm still quite interested in understanding what the minimal ordering is that will ensure correctness

Comment: Haven't grokked the whole thing yet, but how can `//Several threads can end up here` be possible?  For one `bucket`, only one thread can successfully CAS `bucket.lock` from 0 to 1 even with a relaxed RMW.  And why does the next comment talk about `readIndex`?  `updateData` doesn't access  `readIndex` (I guess because it's not a *circular* buffer, jut a one-shot that will fill up, so it worries about the fixed end, not catching up to the oldest unread entry).  I assume that's a typo for `writeIndex`.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you don't need much ordering here, pretty much one-way producer / consumer, so just a release-store somewhere that the reader can sync-with. You very likely don't need per-element `lock` members, just `release` RMWs incrementing a second counter of completed writes instead of claimed slots. (Which the reader does an acquire-load, syncing with the release-sequence.) Hrm, actually I'd have to check how circular buffer lock-free queues do it, since you don't want to all later writers to spin waiting for a slow writer to complete its increment of that. Maybe only SPSC avoids it

Comment: One strategy for MPMC queue using a circular buffer is a sequence number in every bucket which allows for wrap-around of the circular buffer.  [Lock-free Progress Guarantees in a circular buffer queue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45907210) has some info on one such implementation.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, updateData modifies writeIndex only; I fixed the typo.
Several updater threads could successfully lock the same bucket if, say, A and B are about to call bucket.lock.compare_exchange_strong(), but B pauses while A succeeds on the CAS and then proceeds to call writeIndex.compare_exchange_strong() also succeeding.

Comment: At that point A increases writeIndex, modifies bucket's Bucket::data, calls bucket.lock.store(0) and returns. Then, later on, B resumes execution and finds the bucket unlocked (i.e. Bucket::lock == 0), so it succeeds on the call to bucket.lock.compare_exchange_strong(); but when it tries to modify writeIndex, the CAS fails because B's myWriteIndex is now obsolete

Comment: So thread B just calls bucket.lock.store(0) and loops around

Comment: Oh right, because another thread has already unlocked it.  Sequence numbers are a better solution to that problem.  Or wait a minute, a much simpler design would be `myWriteIndex = writeIndex.fetch_add(1, relaxed)` to give every writer a unique index, and use `lock.store(1, release)` as a "write complete" flag *after* you finish updating the data.  The reader can't read a bucket until a `bucket.load(acquire)` sees a non-zero value.  With your current design, how does the reader distinguish a not-yet-written bucket from a write-complete bucket?  They both have `lock = 0`.

Comment: `int64_t myWriteIndex` - how big is this array?  The bit of extra logic to wrap around a circular buffer would probably pay for itself in L3 cache hits vs. page faults from always going forward into new memory, unless you need that whole array to exist when you're done.   Also, that should probably be `size_t` so it's not double-width on 32-bit machines.

Comment: processData() will only operate on write-completed buckets because readIndex is expected to be < writeIndex. So even if updateData locked bucket at index n, and then incremented writeIndex (to n+1) thus making it newly available to the thread calling processData(), the latter will find the bucket locked and just loop around

Comment: And yes, I agree it would be better to implement the container as a ring buffer

Comment: Ok, that probably works, although it's over-complicated and takes a lot more ops in the writer, especially more RMWs.  And more serialization between writers: the next can't get started writing until the previous has taken the lock in the bucket it claimed.  Yeah, `writeIndex` is only incremented while holding the `bucket.lock`.  So that might mean correctness depends on that increment not being visible until after the CAS that claims the lock, so you probably can't make that CAS any weaker than `release`.  I'm too sleepy to figure out more right now.

Comment: (It would probably be good to update the question with some of those design details, like what the point of `lock` is, and what the design intent is for preventing the reader from reading buckets that aren't done writing yet.)

Comment: I added some comments to the code to clarify the use of Bucket::lock.
Which CAS do you recommend be done with mem order not weaker than release? The one to modify bucket.lock, or to modify writeIndex? With which other operation would this release CAS synchronize, and which memory (besides updates to its own atomic var) would it need to serialize to ensure visibility? If you are referring to the CAS for bucket.lock in updateData(): regardless of its curr relaxed ordering, isn't it enough that its a RMW to ensure bucket.lock.load() in processData() sees it locked while bucket is been written?

Comment: Elaborating more on the correctness you brought up and given how RMW ops are specified (and implemented) and assuming coherent caches, the only scenario I can think of is:
readIndex = writeIndex = n at some point, so the reader is just looping around (no more buckets to process); then a writer locks the bucket at n (relaxed CAS) and proceeds to increment writeIndex (another relaxed CAS). 
Unless the aforementioned CAS ops (on 2 diff mem locations, and used in nested conditional statements) get re-ordered by the compiler such that the one on writeIndex happens-before the one in bucket.lock...

Comment: ...the reader will see the bucket at n now available (writeIndex - readIndex = 1), but continue (looping around) if the load on bucket.lock yields 1 (due the writer not yet being done).
So the question is: will a compiler consider the "as-if" rule is not violated by re-ordering those 2 nested conditionals with CAS ops in updateData, and just proceed to do so? In which case, to prevent such re-ordering:

- wouldn't the following line right before calling the writeIndex achieve it cheaply? asm volatile("": : : "memory")

Comment: - or a more proper (but expensive) option in updateData: make the writeIndex load mo acquire, and its CAS mo release?
But again, I believe neither is necessary as that compiler re-ordering will not happen. Thoughts, please?

Comment: I may have another look at this later, but whichever operation you pick to be `release`, the reader side needs to load that one with `acquire`.  Also, `readIndex` can be non-atomic, and preferably in a separate cache-line from `writeIndex` so the load from `buffer[myReadIndex].lock` can get started in parallel with reading `writeIndex` (so the address is already known).  Many CPUs have miss-under-miss caches and are capable of memory-level parallelism with maybe a dozen cache lines in flight.

Comment: `asm volatile("": : : "memory")` is basically `atomic_signal_fence(seq_cst)`.  Not thread_fence.  On x86 it's also `atomic_thread_fence(acq_rel)`, but not on weakly-ordered ISAs.  Exit from a spin-loop could in theory be predicted to happen on some iteration (such as the first, or some later), and that prediction is later confirmed. So generally you can't count on control dependencies doing much for memory ordering of loads, although stores can't commit speculatively.  See [Who's afraid of a big bad optimizing compiler?](https://lwn.net/Articles/793253/) on LWN.

Comment: Yes, for a one-shot buffer (instead of a circular one), readIndex need not be atomic. Also, using alignas and padding, writeIndex and readIndex can be defined in diff cache lines; thus, writers and the reader can proceed w/o creating additional bus traffic.
Enabling acq/rel mo for writeIndex between writers and the reader is IMO not needed bc: (1) if writeIndex changes it is only due to the CAS increment in updateData, which will eventually be loaded by the reader. (2) Bucket::data integrity is guaranteed by acq/rel mo between the updateData CAS on Bucket::lock and its load in processData.

Comment: Yes, agreed, as long as you're still using acq and rel on the `lock`, the reader can be sure the data assignments happen-before its reads.  Unless it somehow can see a `0` from before the writer took the lock, rather than after it unlocked.  With the writer setting `lock=1` before a release operation on `writeIndex`, that's impossible, but with `writeIndex.CAS` being only relaxed, it could be possible unless something else prevents that.  (IDK if real hardware can plausibly reorder the global-visibility of two relaxed RMWs, but ISO C++ allows it.)

Comment: This problem would of course go away if `lock` was actually a `write_done` flag that only gets set to `1` once, after writing `data`.  Or for a circular buffer, if it was a sequence number or something instead of just a lock.  If I have time and interest sometime, I might look at this in more detail as an exercise in memory-ordering, but the fact that there's a more simpler and more efficient solution to the overall problem makes it somewhat less interesting to me.

Comment: Thank you for your comments so far. The link about the optimizing compiler is quite interesting. I understand how stand-alone relaxed CAS ops on diff mem locations could be re-ordered at compile time; but if each leads a nested conditional statements with dependent side-effects, I can't see re-ordering happening w/o violating the as-if rule.
There is a somewhat related question in which you commented about re-ordering of CAS ops, but in the code provided there, they are short-circuited in the 'if' statement:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60382799/independent-read-modify-write-ordering

Comment: Are you writing for ISO C++, or writing for HW that doesn't do anything you don't expect / haven't thought of?  To some degree, that's a separate [cpu-architecture] question; I can't think of a mechanism for run-time reordering either, since a core can't make speculative stores visible to other cores, otherwise they'd also have to roll back on mis-speculation.  Perhaps something like the mechanism for Alpha 21264 violating causality and effectively reordering a dependent load ahead the load of the address?  ([Dependent loads reordering in CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35172125))

Comment: The concern here isn't compile-time reordering, it's run-time reordering of their visibility to other threads.  That's possible if both RMWs are non-speculative: e.g. hardware with a simple ALU built-in to each slice of L3 cache, so cores can send out requests to do an atomic RMW on a certain location and get a response back with the return value.  (Intel RAO is like that except it leaves out the message back to the core, just fire and forget like for incrementing a shared counter, no return value.)  The messages could be sent out in some order, but might modify L3 in the other order.

Comment: That remote-atomic hardware mechanism wouldn't be sufficient to reorder things when there's a control dependency between them; the core would have to wait to hear back before it could retire the branch and be sure the second op (pure store or RMW) was non-speculative, otherwise mis-speculated values could become visible to other cores.  (I'm assuming that's always a no-no in any design.)

Comment: I just updated the question with a refactored updateData, and what I consider a cornerstone question regarding the proposed design with writeIndex and Bucket::lock each using a relaxed CAS